# Visual Studio error when moving directories and building project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I am relatively new to Visual studio and I am learning how to build and make c++ projects in it. Currently, the error I am facing is that my project has a sub-directory called vendor and when I move the location of this, the project doesn't build.

Project structure:

```
Project Dir
- resources
- src
  - vendor
```

I want to move vendor to be inside Project Dir and not inside src:

```
Project Dir
- resources
- src
- vendor
```

Currently when the vendor directory is inside the src directory, the project builds fine with no errors. But when I move the directory to be inside the Project Dir, the build fails and the errors show that visual studio is still expecting the cpp files to be inside the src location:

```
Cannot open source file: 'src\vendor\imgui\imgui_demo.cpp': No such file or directory
Cannot open source file: 'src\vendor\imgui\imgui_draw.cpp': No such file or directory
...(and so on)
```

Things I have tried:

1. I have moved the vendor directory inside the solution itself and then tried building
2. I have cut and pasted the vendor directory in File Explorer and then clicked on the folder in the IDE and selected "Include in project"

Note: There is no issue with includes as I have already updated the additional include directories (and when I press CTRL+LEFT CLICK on the header files they open up which means they are included properly). The only issue is with the cpp files. The IDE still expects them to be in their original location which I don't understand why.

Comment: You probably need to either edit the project file directly (its xml) or do if you are uncomfortable with that fix the files in "Solution Explorer". I expect it will tell you that that the path is wrong.

Comment: Yea, in point 1 thats what I meant when I said I did it inside the solution. I have already tried moving it in the solution explorer. In addition, I have tried to clean the solution, build it, rebuild it and so on. I even manually removed all the bins and intermediate files and rebuild the project

Comment: Maybe remove all files from the moved project inside Solution Explorer and re add 1 by 1 using file -> add ->existing item

Answer (score 0):

To move files, you need to follow the steps below.

1. Move files
2. Right click h/cpp file in Visual Studio ->`Exclude From Project`
3. Add include directories in properties
4. Add Existing Item

Comment: @AK01  May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.